# How to hide div element by body clicking in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide

Hi this is my html code:

```
<span id="transa_noua">Adauga transa noua +</span>
<div id="ad_transa" class="ad_transa2" style="display: none;overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float: left; margin-right:20px;">
        <label for="input_val_transa">Transa de plata</label>
        <input id="nume_transa" type="text"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript functions :

```
$("#transa_noua").click(function(e){
    $("#ad_transa").show();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("body").click(function(e){
  if (e.target.className == "ad_transa"){
     alert("do't hide");  
  }else{    
        $('.ad_transa').css("display","none");
  }
});
```

So, The problem is that I dont want to hide all of the `ad_transa2` class elements. for instance when i click on the input my all div which contains `ad_transa2` class disappear. How can i do that ?

Comment: As IDs must be unique, why not using then the ID selector? If you have more than one element with class AND id equal to `ad_transa`, then your HTML is invalid

Comment: I change the class name into ad_transa2. But I got the same result

Comment: That's not the class that should be changed, that's the ID or better, don't use ID at all. EDIT: in case you have duplicate IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
$("#transa_noua").click(function(){
    $("#ad_transa").show();
});
$(document).on('click', function(){
    $('#ad_transa').hide();
});
$('#ad_transa, #transa_noua').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qx2FJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way which works:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#element-want-hidden').length) {
    if ($('#element-want-hidden').is(':visible')) {
      $('#element-want-hidden').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(document).click (event) ->
    if !$(event.target).closest('#element-want-hidden').length
      if $('#element-want-hidden').is(':visible')
        $('#element-want-hidden').hide()
    return
```

It looks for the closest element and that can be itself so it will look for itself and allow you to click anywhere on the page and the element will hide again.